# Mobile app development environment for Windows machine

Tags: android, ios, windows, mobile

I want to create a mobile app from scratch, but I'm not sure what development environment to use. I have a Windows machine, so I can't use Xcode. I think Visual Studio has mobile app programming capabilities? But I am not sure. I have never built a mobile app before. For all other coding projects I have used Visual Studio Code.

I am also wondering: for technical interviews, I know employers like to see projects that you have worked on outside of school/work. Can I consider this app (once I complete it) as a project that I can talk about during an interview even if I don't publish it to an app store? Or is this frowned upon?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regardless of what tool you use, you need a Mac or access to a Mac in the cloud if you want to build for iOS devices.  I guess you could show the source code for your app as an example of your work in interviews.

Comment: What if I built android apps?

Comment: Yes, you can build Android apps on Windows.

Comment: What environment could I use for that? Would Visual Studio work?

Comment: Visual studio code is popular.  Providing recommendations is off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: Android Studio is the official tool for building android Apps. You can also use it with additional plugins to build cross platform Apps with Flutter. Other popular options are a) Visual Studio for cross platform apps with Xamarin and b) VS Code for React Native.